# send files to webserver without FTP

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

we have always problems sending files from our ERP to our linux-webserver (1und1) via FTP. we sent many files an the 1und1 ftp-server closes sometimes our connections. the support said us, that we can only open 2 ftp-connections from our ip-adresse.
now my question : how can we send the files to the server without using FTP ?

Comment: Use `scp` if it is a host you can `ssh` into.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).